# If statement doesn't always go off even when conditions are meet?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a simple Java game for fun and I am running into a problem. When ever I run the code It will spit out a random number for the enemy but it won't trigger the if then statement all the time. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here\
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int playerlevel = 1;
    int playermaxdamage = 9;
    int playermindamage = 1;
    int playerhealthrng = rnd.nextInt(11 - 7) + 7;
    int playerhealth = playerlevel * playerhealthrng;   
    int playerdamage = rnd.nextInt(playermaxdamage - playermindamage) + 1;
    int enemytyperngmax = 10;
    int enemytyperngmin = 1;
    int enemytyperngreal = 0;
    int enemyratdamagemaxrng = 3;
    int enemyratdamageminrng = 1;
    int enemyrathealthmaxrng = 5;
    int enemyrathealthminrng = 1;
    int enemyratnumberrangehigh = 5;
    int enemyratnumberrangelow = 1;
    int noenemynumberrangehigh = 6;
    int noenemynumberrangelow = 9;
    int enemydragonnumberrangehigh = 10;
    int enemydragonnumberrangelow = 10;
    int enemyrathealthreal = rnd.nextInt (enemyrathealthmaxrng - enemyrathealthminrng) + 1;
    int enemytyperng = rnd.nextInt(enemytyperngmax - enemytyperngmin) + 1;

    String asktowalk = "Do you want to move forward?"; 
    String playerinfolevel = ("Player's Current level is " + playerlevel);
    String playerinfohealth = ("Player's Current Health is " + playerhealth);
    String playerdamagedealt = ("Player did " + playerdamage + " to enemy");
    String enemyratinfo = ("A Rat has appered with " + (enemyrathealthreal) + " Hp");
    String enemynoninfo = ("You are Safe . . . for now");
    String enemydragoninfo = ("You have uncovered a Danges beast he swings for 2,147,483,647 Damange");         

    enemyratdamagemaxrng = rnd.nextInt(enemyratdamagemaxrng - enemyratdamageminrng) + 1;

    System.out.println(enemyratdamagemaxrng);

    if (enemytyperng > enemyratnumberrangelow && enemytyperng < enemyratnumberrangehigh)
        System.out.println(enemyratinfo);

    if (enemytyperng > noenemynumberrangelow && enemytyperng < noenemynumberrangehigh)
        System.out.println(enemynoninfo);

    if (enemytyperng == enemydragonnumberrangehigh)
        System.out.println(enemydragoninfo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in your IDE debugger? If not, please do that first.  If you have, then explain what you found.

Comment: Have you considered adding some `else` if(s)?

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  Show us the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: welcome to SO.  For testing use known vlaues (not random) for `enemyrathealthreal` and `enemytyperng`. If yo don't get what you expect, add their values and expected output to the post.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
if (enemytyperng > noenemynumberrangelow && enemytyperng < noenemynumberrangehigh)
        System.out.println(enemynoninfo);
```

if enemytyperng is greater than 9 AND if enemytyprng is less than 6; display enemynoninfo.

However, it is impossible for a value to be BOTH greater than 9 AND less than 6. (Perhaps you meant to use OR || operator?) Or, perhaps you got those values mixed up when assigning them to your variables.

Also, you are randomly generating a number between 0 and 8 and then adding 1. So it will never be greater than 9. Remember, the random number generator is exclusive, meaning rnd.nextInt(9) will only generate values between 0 and 8.

The same applies to your last if statement. It will never equal 10 because the max value it can equal is 9.

So if you want to generate a random number between 1 and 10; try

```
rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

But what you have is essentially

```
rand.nextInt(9) + 1;
```

Side note: There are a lot of concerns with the code you wrote. I strongly recommend picking up an actual college level textbook and working your way through from start to finish.